# Eliminar filas #N/D con una macro

Tags: excel

me pregunto si es posible a través de una macro poder eliminar toda una fila cuando el resultado de un buscarv es #N/D, trate de hacerlo por la opción de grabar macro con un filtro y eliminar los que no coinciden, pero al correr la macro este me corre la formula de buscarv y solo me deja las primeras filas.

Probé este código, pero me esta dando error 13 no coinciden los tipos

```
Dim Borrar As Range
Dim i As Long

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Exportar")
    For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count 
        If .Cells(i, "D") = "#N/D" Then
            If Borrar Is Nothing Then
                Set Borrar = .Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set Borrar = Union(Borrar, .Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

Borrar.EntireRow.Delete 

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Cells(i, "D")` devuelve un valor de tipo rango.

`.Cells(i, "D").value` devuelven un tipo de dato "Error", porque la formula devuelve un error.

En ambos casos no coincide con "#N/D" que es de tipo texto.

la solución es usar .Text, queda así:

```
.Cells(i, "D").Text
```

En el ciclo for también hay un detalle, si por ejemplo son 10 filas a procesar, pero como estas iniciando el ciclo en el 2, significa que el ciclo se repetirá 9 veces, entiendo que lo inicias en 2 porque es la primera fila a procesar es la numero 2, pero una cosa es en que fila inicia y otra es la cantidad de veces que se repite el ciclo.

Esto se puede arreglar de 2 formas.

1.- en cada `.Cells(i` se le suma 1 a i, quedando así: `.Cells(i +1`

2.- Al propio conteo de filas le sumas 1: `.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1`

Así queda el código.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Borrar As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja2")
        For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            If .Cells(i, "D").Text = "#N/D" Then
                If Borrar Is Nothing Then
                    Set Borrar = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set Borrar = Union(Borrar, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    Borrar.EntireRow.Delete
    
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda , agradezco mucho me explicación.